# Unable to pass string parameter to php function via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making the following jquery ajax call to a codeigniter php function:

```
    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "Ajax/getHtml",
                        data: { u : 'http://stackoverflow.com/' },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'html',       
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);

                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('error');
                                console.log(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
```

The requested php function is :

```
public function getHtml() {
        var_dump($_POST);
        $url = $_POST['u'];
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        echo ($result);
}
```

var_dump($_POST) yields:

```
array(0) { }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: setting contentType option is telling the request what data type you are sending to the server, php by default doesnt know how to receive/process json, you would have to read the raw input to get it. Remove the contentType option

Comment: Have you tried changing content type?

Comment: you don't need to set the content type, omit that part and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php will not populate the $_POST array if the content type of the request is `application/json; charset=utf-8`, also you aren't sending json.  Just remove the content type line and the proper(default) content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will be set.